# keep h1 content within a div

Tags: html, css, responsive

with the following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Company Home Page with Flexbox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <div class="about">
            <h4><span>A work selection by </span><a class="sobre" href="">sfgndfyj</a></h4>
        </div>
    </header>

    <main>
        
        <article class="uno">
                <h1>
                    <span id="ppal" class="title_part" style="display: block; font-size: 12vw";>stills & moving image</span>

                    <span id="sec" class="title_part" style="display: block; font-size: 11vw";>TECHNICAL PRODUCTION</span>
                </h1>
        </article>

        <article class="dos">

        </article>

    </main>

</body>
</html>
```

and the following css:

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;

}
body {
    max-width: 1500px;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

/* -------------------------------------- fonts */

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Alternate Gothic';
    src: url('Alternate Gothic W01 No 3.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Times Roman';
    src: url('OPTITimes-Roman.otf') format('opentype');
}

.sobre {
    color: black;
}

.sobre:hover {
    transition: background-color .1s ease-out,color .1s ease-out;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Alternate Gothic';
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: clamp(.5rem, 10vw, 1rem);
    
    }

h4 {
    font-weight: lighter;
    letter-spacing: .1rem;

}

#ppal {
    word-spacing: 90%;
}

.title_part {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;

}

/* --------------------------------- spacing */

.about {
    text-align: center;    
    margin: 0 5vw;
}

header {
    border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000;
    margin: 0 2.5rem;

}

.dos {
    border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000;
    margin: 0 2.5rem;
    
}
```

I have tried for hours to find out why the h1 goes beyond the limits of its parent.

I am trying to keep h1 in two lines of (responsive) text. When you grow the window it goes above the 1600px limit placed on the body.
No matter if I try max-width, overflow, etc that it keeps getting out the box.

Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong? Im trying to figure out how to stop the h1 to go beyond the above limit.

Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below what I accept as a solution to the issue I was having with h1.

It does not jump to a new line once I changed the units applied on index.html / .uno / span you can see applied on the very first post, and some tweaking on the css that you can see hereunder.

I did not need white-space.

I welcome any feedback to fine tune it.

(index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Company Home Page with Flexbox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <div class="about">
            <h4><span>A work selection by </span><a class="sobre" href="">sfgndfyj</a></h4>
        </div>
    </header>

    <main>

        <article class="uno">
            <h1>
                <span id="ppal" class="title_part" style="display: block;";>stills & moving image</span>

                <span id="sec" class="title_part" style="display: block;";>TECHNICAL PRODUCTION</span>
                </h1>
        </article>

        <article class="dos">       
        </article>

    </main>

</body>
```

(style.css)

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;

}
body {
    max-width: 1500px;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

/* -------------------------------------- fonts */

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Alternate Gothic';
    src: url('Alternate Gothic W01 No 3.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Times Roman';
    src: url('OPTITimes-Roman.otf') format('opentype');
}

.sobre {
    color: black;
}

.sobre:hover {
    transition: background-color .1s ease-out,color .1s ease-out;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Alternate Gothic';
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: clamp(1rem, 11.3vw, 11rem);
    margin: 2rem 0;
    }

h4 {
    font-weight: lighter;
    letter-spacing: .1rem;
    font-size: clamp(.1rem, 2.5vw, 1rem);
}

#ppal {
    font-size: 50%;
    font-weight: 400;
    word-spacing: 100%;
}

#sec {
    word-spacing: 30%;
}

.title_part {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;

}

/* --------------------------------- spacing */

.about {
    text-align: center;    
    margin: 0 5vw;
}

header {
    border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000;
    margin: 0 1rem;

}

.dos {
    border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000;
    margin: 0 1rem;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    
}
```

Best

Answer (score 1):

It is the  `white-space: nowrap;` which prevents your span to break your lines when the content is filled in the parent. Remove that and your code will work fine

**Working Fiddle**

```css
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 16px;
}

body {
    max-width: 1600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

main {
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Alternate Gothic";
    src: url("Alternate Gothic W01 No 3.ttf") format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Times Roman";
    src: url("OPTITimes-Roman.otf") format("opentype");
}

.about {
    text-align: center;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000;
    margin: 0 5vw;
}

.fulltitle {
}

h1 {
    font-family: "Alternate Gothic";
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
}

.uno {
    border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000;
    margin: 0 4vw;
    max-width: 1600px;
    position: relative;
}

.title_part {
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* white-space: nowrap; */
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="about">
    <h4><span>A work selection by </span><a href="">mfowmyoxsnk</a></h4>
    </div>
</header>

<main>
    <article class="uno">
    <div class="fulltitle">
        <h1>
        <span class="title_part" style="display: block; font-size: 12vw" ;
            >stills & moving image</span
        >

        <span class="title_part" style="display: block; font-size: 11vw" ;
            >TECHNICAL PRODUCTION</span
        >
        </h1>
    </div>
    </article>

    <article class="dos"></article>
</main>
```

Comment: thank you for the prompt reply. I would like to keep the h1 in two lines. Actually, Im trying to make it responsive so the white-space: nowrap is helping me (?) with that

Comment: @petrus Then how should the h1  look like when the content grows out of the parent?

Comment: It seems h1 can stop growing to avoid getting out of the parent which, is what Im trying  to achieve with max-width: 1600px; without any success. So my question would be how can I stop h1 to grow out of the parent

Answer (score 0):

If you want your title to return to the line you have to put wrap like this

```
white-space: wrap;
```

Comment: thanks for reaching out, no joy with white-space: wrap; as it splits my line in two (so they become 2+)

Answer (score 0):

Like the others have said you need to remove the "white-space", this will cause the text to go in to two lines. If you want to prevent this behavior you will have to change the font-size to be smaller.

After that, remove the margin from ".uno". This will ensure that the h1 element remains in the div. The margin currently pushes it out the div no matter the size of the child, even if the text is responsive.

Another recommendation beyond what you're looking for, instead of wrapping two spans in a single "h1", remove the h1, and replace the two spans with 1 "h1" element and the other with a "h2" or whatever subheader element depending on the size you want. If you are trying to modify the positions of elements(center, left, right) instead of margins I recommend looking into flexbox.

```
.uno {
    border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000;
    max-width: 1600px;
    position: relative;
}

.title_part {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

<div class="fulltitle">
    <h1 class="title_part" style="display: block; font-size: 5vw;";>stills & moving image</h1>
    <h2 class="title_part" style="display: block; font-size: 3vw; text-align: center; ">TECHNICAL PRODUCTION</h2>
</div>
```

My bad for the formatting, I'm still learning how to post answers on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that:

(index.html)

- font-size placed in span is making it grow endlessly because of the vw.

(style.css)

- clamp will make it responsive the  way I want to, with a max-limit to whatever I want in the final layout.

Posting what I get as soon as I have it ready